# Does Diesel support the Postgres `point` type?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'd like to use the [point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-geometric.html) Postgres type. I don't see this type listed [here](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/types/index.html) in the types list for Diesel.

What is the correct way to write a model that includes a `point` column?

Comment: I know it is not exactly PostGIS, but I suspect the answer is similar to this one: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/232#issuecomment-193934393. I.e. it would require creating an extension to Diesel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this Diesel GitHub issue](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/491) and the types available in [`diesel::pg::types`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/types/index.html) and [`diesel::types`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/types/index.html), there doesn't seem to be any support for these types.

To write a model that includes a `point` column, you would need to make `point` a value Diesel can understand. This starts by implementing the `FromSql` trait for a `Point` type and then implementing all the things needed for that. For such an extension, look at [this PR](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/pull/1021/files).